# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_dblib.so' ON CENTOS 8 PHP 8

Tags: php, pdo, package, ini, php-8

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_dblib.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_dblib.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_dblib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules
/pdo_dblib.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_dblib.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.0.25 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2022 09:42:31) ( NTS gcc x86_64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.25, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

In /etc/php.d/
My pfo_dblib.ini contains extension = pdo_dblib.so

Comment: *pdo_dblib.ini my bad

Comment: How did you install the extension? Does the file exist in any of the directories listed?

Comment: (Note: there's an `[edit]` link under the question for correcting typos and adding information; as noted on the [tour] the site isn't intended to act as a forum, so the Question should contain all the main information for the page.)